# Let $A$ and $B$ be n x n matrices. $A$ and $AB$ are invertible. Prove that $B$ is invertible by writing it as the product of two invertible matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

> Let $A$ and $B$ be n x n matrices. $A$ and $AB$ are invertible. Prove that $B$ is invertible by writing it as the product of two invertible matrices.

Proof for linear algebra class I'm having trouble with.

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices.
Let $A$ and $AB$ be invertible.
Since $AB$ is invertible,

$(AB)^{-1}(AB) = I$

From here is it possible to group $A$ and $A^{-1}$ together? or is there another step in between?

Comment: Could you re-edit your question with your attempted proof by counter example?

Comment: "Proof by counterexample"?

Comment: It's impossible to prove a statement true by giving a counterexample. So if that's what you mean by "proof by counterexample," you will never get there. If you mean "proof by *contradiction*" that's probably not going to be productive either. There is a one-line direct proof.

Comment: $B = A^{-1}(AB)$ expresses $B$ as a product of two invertible matrices.

Comment: $AB$ has an inverse, so $(AB)^{-1}AB = I$, so $B$ has an inverse: $(AB)^{-1}A$.

Comment: Apologies, I meant proof by contradiction, and yes, I was going about it the wrong way. I'm still new at using this site, I'll edit the post with my current work to see if I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Before writing the proof, I had $(AB)^{-1}AB = I$ in mind like you did. However, saying straight out that $B^{-1} = (AB)^{-1}A$ and claiming that as your proof is not valid since you had to assume that $B$ was invertible. I then took the inverse of both sides and I got $B = A^{-1}(AB)$ - here it is not hard to see that the right hand side will reduce to the left hand side. So we can begin our proof:

Let $B = A^{-1}(AB)$ and we claim that $B^{-1} = (AB)^{-1}A$ since $AB$ and $A$ are invertible. Now,
$$BB^{-1} = A^{-1}(AB)(AB)^{-1}A = A^{-1}A = I$$

Therefore our expression for $B^{-1}$ is an inverse of $B$. Remember that although we only showed that $B^{-1}$ is a right inverse of $B$, it is actually also a left inverse of $B$ $(B^{-1}B = (AB)^{-1}AA^{-1}(AB) = (AB)^{-1}(AB) = I)$.

Comment: A product of invertible matrices is invertible. If $B=A^{-1}(AB)$, this is a product of two matrices that are invertible by assumption, so there is no need to try to construct $B^{-1}$ or verify that constructed matrix is the inverse. Hence the instruction given (which granted, the OP hid in the subject line rather than stating it in the post)...